# Select Logic in Query. Is this possible in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Im trying to implement some sort of logic on the select statement of the query. I want it so that if no attribute is given, or if the inAttribute is 'NONE'; it will return the date and ALL of the values (compprice, compspread,price,spread,run).

If a value was given to in attribute then i want it to return the value it requested for (Refer to the case statement i tried to do).

Below is my attempt at it, and it is just not working. Any help please?

```
 SELECT 
    mi.date,
    IF inAttribute = '' THEN

              mi.compprice, 
              mi.compspread, 
              mi.price, 
              mi.spread, 
              mi.run
              ELSE
                 CASE inAttribute
                      WHEN 'CP' THEN  mi.compprice, 
                      WHEN 'CS THEN mi.compspread, 
                      WHEN 'MP' THEN  mi.price, 
                      WHEN 'MS' THEN mi.spread, 
                      WHEN 'R' THEN mi.run
                 END 
    END IF
    FROM userValueTable mi
    WHERE mi.index_family = inIdxFamily
    AND mi.index_id = inIdxId
    AND mi.date_>= inStartDate
    AND mi.date_<= inEndDate
    ORDER by mi.date_ ASC;
```

Comment: You can't do this directly with SQL.  A SQL statement specifies what columnsa are returned, so you cannot return a variable number of columns.  There are kludges . . . such as using XML or using dynamic SQL (via a prepare statement).

Comment: This is not possible in pure SQL.  You can use dynamic SQL to fire different queries depending on input parameters.

Comment: Missing a quote at the end of the second literal in the case statement too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have an `IF` for SQL. Use `CASE` instead - it can act like a C/C#/Java/etc `switch - case` as you have it in your query, and it can also act like an `if`.

Also, as mentioned above:

- You're stuck with returning a constant number of columns unless you use dynamic SQL
- In Oracle, `''` is treated as NULL so instead of `= ''` use `IS NULL`.

If you don't want to go to Dynamic SQL, you could add a "type" column to your select list and then null out any inapplicable values. Your downstream logic could pick the values to use (or ignore) based on the type. Here's an example:

```
SELECT
  mi.date,
  CASE
    WHEN inAttribute IS NULL THEN 'inAttrNull'
    ELSE 'inAttrNotNull'
    END AS RecordType,
  CASE WHEN inAttribute IS NULL THEN mi.compprice END AS compprice,
  CASE WHEN inAttribute IS NULL THEN mi.compspread END AS compspread,
  CASE WHEN inAttribute IS NULL THEN mi.price END AS price,
  CASE WHEN inAttribute IS NULL THEN mi.spread END AS spread,
  CASE WHEN inAttribute IS NULL THEN mi.run END AS run,
  CASE inAttribute
    WHEN 'CP' THEN mi.compprice
    WHEN 'CS' THEN mi.compspread
    WHEN 'MP' THEN mi.price
    WHEN 'MS' THEN mi.spread
    WHEN 'R'  THEN mi.run
  END AS SpecialValue
FROM userValueTable mi
... and your WHERE and ORDER BY clauses
```

You'll get a result set something like this:

```
RecordType    compprice  compspread price      spread     run        specialvalue
------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------
inAttrNotNull     (null)      (null)    (null)     (null)     (null)      1234.56
inAttrNull        111.11      222.22    333.33     444.44     555.55       (null)
```

I know this isn't what you wanted, but it may be something you can work with as an alternative.

Comment: everything is fine, but run is a varchar, so any idea on how i can fix that so i dont get incosistent data type error

Comment: also, i wanted it to return 1 column or all 5; not 5 all the time

Comment: You could use `TO_CHAR` to convert `compprice`, `compspread`, etc to character. That would take care of the inconsistent data type, but "1 or all 5" can't be done without Dynamic SQL. My answer is just an alternative to Dynamic SQL, and it may or may not work in your situation. The idea is that if `RecordType` is `inAttrNull` you ignore column `specialvalue` and if it's `inAttrNotNull` you ignore the others (`compprice`, `compspread`, etc.).

Comment: You might be interested in trying the Nvl2() function... "NVL2(inAttribute,Null,mi.compprice) compprice"

Comment: @DavidAldridge - thanks! I haven't used that in so long that I'd completely forgotten about it. Its brevity is a great fit for this situation.

Comment: @EdGibbs not very ANSI though, I suspect.

Comment: Nope, though that alone would never stop me from using it. I'd love to say I switched to `CASE` because it's a standard, but the real reason is that I do some SQL Server and MySQL in addition to Oracle, and `CASE` works in all three. Laziness was the deciding factor here :)

Answer (score 2):

Few remarks

You can't have variable column list from one line to another.

'' is equal to NULL, comparing NULL with equality ( = ) is always false.

you can have some fixed number of columns and set value of any column using CASE clause.

Answer (score 0):

There is no IF in Oracle SQL, only in PL/SQL. You have to rewrite it to CASE. The same as you did in your query in ELSE part (you missed a single closing quote after 'CS' THEN...).

```
SELECT ...
 (CASE WHEN inAttribute IS NULL THEN mi.compprice
     WHEN .... THEN...
     WHEN .... THEN...
     ...
 ELSE ...
 END) AS some_column_alias
FROM ...
```